# Is IO with O_DIRECT less safe for lacking of address checking?

Tags: linux, io, kernel

Because as mentioned in book [Understanding The Linux Kernel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005652), normal IO (without `O_DIRECT`) would do data copy by call function of `copy_to_user()` or `copy_from_user()`. So beside `access_ok()`, a more complete user address parameter cheching is done by a mechanism named (by the book) as “Dynamic Address Checking: The Fix-up Code” , which is as bellow:

> the PC address of the exact copy instruction inside copy_to_user() or
>   copy_from_user() are set into an __ex_table, When there is a wrong
>   user address input through the system call, the page fault handler
>   would do bellow check so system call is more safe:
>
> ———————————————————————
>
> ```
>  if PC is in __ex_table then just kill the user program
>
>  else kernel panic
> ```
>
> ———————————————————————

My question is since the `O_DIRECT` mostly does not do user/kernel copy, so it might be less safe from kernel perspective because its lack of above dynamic address checking?

Thanks for help.

Edit:

Per Tsyvarev's reply, "less safe" might be not much precise, my question can be further elaberated as:
When a program do direct I/O and it provides wrong address, then which cases of bellow will happen:

1. the program will be killed (since program without O_DIRECT will be killed, so if program with O_DIRECT will not get killed, I considered it is not as safe in my upper question )
2. or will the kernel just panic
3. or do nothing

Maybe my question is too code specific, and I need do some experiments and code reading to find answer myself :)
thanks

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "less safe". Linux kernel is safe against any user action, be it normal reading of the file or `O_DIRECT` reading. If some action may affects on safety (like kernel module loading), the it requires privileged user to perform this operation.

Comment: see my "edit" above~